# Why my menu don't work c++ case switch

Tags: c++, menu

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwabT.png)

i'm only start in c++ and i have problem with my class homework
a simple problem i hope
I know that i have only 2 methods of 1 and 2 in menu,but it don't work for first and second together?
my code `
[Link] http://pastebin.com/b8CRUJbw

Comment: Please edit your question to contain the code ...

Comment: i'm added link with my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cin>>tester1; 
while(!cin) { // If integers are not inputted
    cin.clear(); // Clear the error flag and stream buffer
    cin.sync();
    cout << "Please enter an integer!!" << endl;
    cout << " >>";
    cin>>tester1; // Input again
}
array[counter].registry=tester1;
```

Comment: but a need have lengthofArray it is max value of length of my Array
And i need to have currentSize 

for example
[1][2][3][ ][ ][ ]
lengthofArray = 6
currentSize = 3

Comment: @Anastasiia Just change to `aa=new int[lengthOfArray];`